# Proguard doesn't hide class and folder names in Android

Tags: java, android, class, proguard

I Have an Android application that I wanted to obfuscate using ProGuard.

After some time I finally managed to make it work with all my external libraries that I am using. I Configure my ProGuard for release build using gradle

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
```

There is one problem tho.

I am testing my obfuscated code with Smali2Java, which can read code and methods very well if its not obfuscated, and when it is, you can only see variables and imports. **The problem is that you can also see class names and folders.** It's very important for me to hide them so user couldn't see project structure and code like this:

```
public class DtosToPrintRequestsMapper {
    private final TransactionLineCreator a;
    private final ProtocolDiscountCreator b;
    private final ProtocolPaymentCreator c;
}
```

**I do not want user to be able to see those things. As well as folders structure in my project.**

Here is my proguard-rules:

```
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:

# ignore warnings
-dontwarn com.google.common.**
-dontwarn com.octo.**
-dontwarn com.squareup.javawriter.**
-dontwarn okio.**

# Butterknife
-dontwarn butterknife.internal.**
-keep class **$$ViewInjector { *; }
-keepnames class * { @butterknife.InjectView *;}

# Dagger
-dontwarn dagger.**
-keepclassmembers,allowobfuscation class * {
    @javax.inject.* *;
    @dagger.* *;
    <init>();
}
-keep class dagger.* { *; }
-keep class javax.inject.* { *; }
-keep class * extends dagger.internal.Binding
-keep class * extends dagger.internal.ModuleAdapter
-keep class * extends dagger.internal.StaticInjection
-keep class * extends dagger.internal.BindingsGroup

-keep class com.someapp.waiterapp.infrastructure.someappModule
-keep class com.someapp.waiterapp.infrastructure.AndroidModule
-keep class com.someapp.waiterapp.infrastructure.RootModule
-keep class dagger.Lazy

# Retrofit, OkHttp, Gson
-dontwarn retrofit.**
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes Signature
-keep class com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-keep interface com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }

-keepattributes Exceptions
-keep class retrofit.** { *; }
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit.http.* <methods>;
}
-keep class com.someapp.waiterapp.lib.api.contract.** { *; }
-keepclassmembernames interface * {
    @retrofit.http.* <methods>;
}
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }

# Otto
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepclassmembers class ** {
    @com.squareup.otto.Subscribe public *;
    @com.squareup.otto.Produce public *;
}
```

I've tried to change

```
keepnames class * { @butterknife.InjectView *;}
```

to

```
keep class * { @butterknife.InjectView *;}
```

And

```
keepclassmembernames interface
```

to

```
keepclassmembers interface
```

but with no result.

If there is something that comes to your mind I could do to rename those class and folder names to typical a/b/c/d help would be very much appreciated.